# Notice: Undefined indexes : username, first_name,last_name in…index.php

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Не могу разобраться, сделал подключение к БД , проверил,всё работает, проверил запросом на добавления строки в БД(строку добавило, всё работает).Хочу вывести на экран массив,а не выводи и пишет что таких индексов не существует, которые заданы в таблице.Вот мой код

```
***index.php***
require_once("../includes/database.php");
require_once("../includes/users.php");
if(isset ($database)) {echo"true";}else {echo "false";}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
$found_user = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
echo $found_user['username'];

echo "<hr />";

$found_user = User::find_by_id(1);
echo $found_user['username'];

echo "<hr />";

$user_set = User::find_all();
while ($user = $database->fetch_array($user_set)) {
    echo "User: ". $user['username'] ."<br />";
    echo "Name: ". $user['first_name'] . " " . $user['last_name'] ."<br /><br />";
}
```

Файл users.php

```
class User{
    public static function find_all(){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
        return $result_set;
    }

    public static function find_by_id($id=0){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
        $found =$database->fetch_array($result_set);
        return $found;
    }
}
```

Проверяю через var_dump переменнную $users выдает (array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "olegsavchuk12" [2]=> string(4) "1111" [3]=> string(4) "Oleg" [4]=> string(7) "Savchuk" } })

Comment: И снова "ООП" с global и ни малейшего желания учиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы используете метод `fetch_array()`. Попробуйте `fetch_assoc()`.
И каким драйвером Базы Данных вы пользуетесь ?

Использовать `glodal` не есть хорошо, и даже плохо. В конструкторе можно передавать драйвер БД. Примерно так:

```
class Users { // Интуитивно понятно, что класс не User, а Users.
    protected $database;

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function find_all() {
        // Код метода ...  используйте $this->database
    }

    public function find_by_id($id = 0){
        // Точно так же ..
    }
}
```

Потом создавать экземпляр:

```
$users = new Users($database);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, проблема была в fetch_array(). Я пол дня сидел не мог понять в чем проблема)

Comment: Увы, этот ответ ему не поможет.